# Is there any way to know if a DOS application uses graphics mode in it or not?

Tags: windows, dos, x86-16, 16-bit, dosbox

I am currently trying to create a program that detects if a DOS executable uses non-text mode in it or not.

I am uncertain if there is any semantics for it in the header of the 16-bit executable but the only way I found out (for now), is to check the value of AX every time `int 10h`(CD10) is found in the code (that is by using some debugger like technology)

Is there any easier and more efficient way to know if a DOS executable might use graphics mode in it or is this the only possible way to achieve it?

Also, is it possible to execute over to a specific offset in the code (position in the exe file) and then find the value of AX at that point of time (programmatically)?

The proposed solution/code can be purely written in Windows (if needed)

(I personally feel the method proposed by me might not be 100% accurate as the value of AX might depend on the flow of the program)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209816/discussion-on-question-by-mr-stackoverflow-is-there-any-way-to-know-if-a-dos-ap).